# how to get next weeks date in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Currently in my build i am using 
dynamic parameter (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Dynamic+Parameter+Plug-in) to get current date and time. I use this variable and set it part of my build process.

How to get next weeks date for wednesday?
For example: currently todays date is 10/14/2014. Next week wednesday date is 10/19/2014.

I cannot seem to find any other plugins or scripts that does this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use execute shell and run something like:

```
$ date -d "+7 days"
```

For example,

```
$ date -d "+14 days" +%d"/"%m"/"%y
```

will be the next today in two weeks date - 03/12/14.
The date command is awesome. I highly recommend you to use it.

Good luck :)